# Custom Program Errors - Need Better Documentation?

Tags: solana-program, spl-token

I have been working with compressing NFTs and I experience custom program errors in transactions like this one

```
custom program error: 0xbc4
```

This might not be the most up to date it could be, it has some error handling though:

https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/master/token/program/src/error.rs

Comment: did you ever figure this out @solanagirl?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If that's from an Anchor program, the error is this:

```
#[msg("The program expected this account to be already initialized")]
AccountNotInitialized,
```

https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/master/lang/src/error.rs#L185